# ASP.net mvc 5 excel data reader

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm doing the following

```
    var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
```

however, i get the error on the second line saying

> "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Excel.IExcelDataReader' to 'Assignment9.Controllers.IExcelDataReader'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I have added install-package exceldatareader, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From the details of the exception you have another type with the same name in the `Assignment9.Controllers` namespace . Check your project (probably the `Assignment9/Controllers` folder) to see if you created another `IExcelDataReader` that is causing the conflict. The assumption here is that `Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader` actually returns `Excel.IExcelDataReader`